# this SQL appears to be giving weird results with multiple JOINS, how do I correct it?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, join

I have several Rails Active Record Models:  ContactEmails, ContactCalls, ContactPostalcards.

Each one represent a completed activity: a completed email, call, or postalcard to a specific Contact, and each Contact belongs to a Company.

I want a high-level summary by Company of all the Emails, Calls, and Postalcards within a specific date range:

```
def self.get_list(report_start_date, report_end_date)

    self.find :all,
      :select => "companies.name AS co_name, 
              companies.id AS comp_id, 
              COUNT(contact_emails.id) AS email_count, 
              COUNT(contact_calls.id) AS call_count, 
              COUNT(contact_letters.id) AS letter_count, 
              COUNT(contact_postalcards.id) AS postalcard_count",

      :conditions => ['contact_emails.date_sent < ? and contact_emails.date_sent > ? or
                       contact_calls.date_sent < ? and contact_calls.date_sent > ?', 
                  report_end_date, report_start_date, report_end_date, report_start_date],

      :joins => [
        "LEFT JOIN companies ON companies.id = contacts.company_id",
        "LEFT JOIN contact_emails ON contact_emails.contact_id = contacts.id",
        "LEFT JOIN contact_letters ON contact_letters.contact_id = contacts.id",
        "LEFT JOIN contact_postalcards ON contact_postalcards.contact_id = contacts.id",
        "LEFT JOIN contact_calls ON contact_calls.contact_id = contacts.id"
       ],
     #:group => "companies.id"
      :group => "companies.name"
  end
```

This is how I output the matrix in my View:

```
<% @matrix_summary.each do |item| %>      
<tr>
   <td><%= link_to item.co_name, company_path(item.comp_id) %></td>
   <td><%= item.email_count %> </td>
   <td><%= item.postalcard_count %></td>
   <td><%= item.call_count %></td>
<% end %>
</tr>
```

My expectation is each row should represent a Company, with the respective Email, Postalcard and Call counts for that one company (across all Contacts).

What I get is the same value (and a wrong value at that) for all Activities.

What am I doing that's not right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have few companies, than @klew's suggestion is probably the way to go. If you have many and only want to run one query, here's a gist which illustrates using subqueries to get all of the counts: http://gist.github.com/602944

It's split into two examples, the first is really introductory to how the subqueries will work, the second removes all the redundancy so it's easier to edit in the future.

Comment: I will probably have many companies -- many meaning for a specific user 10-20 companies, and the query could be run by multiple users over different data sets....I don't have to use one query, but thought it could be more efficient (but then, I will trade simplicity for efficiency at this stage)....

Comment: I +1 because this looks like the comprehensive solution -- however, I think at this stage, I'm leaning towards readability because I'm realizing since I'm still developing early I need to understand it more fully but will actually start to review and implement your solution as I get a better handle....

Comment: I  will probably need to use yours, I'm not sure if the other version address it...they don't address how do I generate which companies to actually display (only those for which there is an activity count >0)....yours takes care of that, right?

Comment: @Angela #activityCounts: You could do that by adding `:conditions => %w(email_count call_count letter_count postalcard_count).map{|x| "#{x} is not null"}.join(' OR ')` to the final query.

Answer (score 1):

What your query appears to be doing (I know SQL but not Rails) is returning a line for each postcard, email etc which are then grouped.  Count simply counts the number of lines in the group so the number you get will be the total number of the 4 types.

I suspect you will need to use a managed SQL loop to loop through the customers and then to count the records in each category for each customer and then summarize the information.

Answer (score 0):

Run your server log, (tail -f log/development.log) and then run your action in browser.
See the query it generated in the logs. Copy that query, and execute it in a SQL console. Does it give the right answers?

Secondly, if you want to perform so heavy customization of Rails' find, I would recommend you rather use 
a) find_by_sql or
b) ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute() etc.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest changing each of your COUNT(*fieldname*) to be COUNT(DISTINCT *fieldname*) - so for example, `COUNT(contact_emails.id) AS email_count` would become `COUNT(DISTINCT contact_emails.id) AS email_count` .

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your models look like this:

```
# Company model
has_many :contacts
has_many :contact_emails, :through => :contacts
has_many :contact_calls, :through => :contacts
has_many :contact_letters, :through => :contacts
has_many :contact_postalcard, :through => :contacts

# Contact model
has_many :contact_emails
has_many :contact_calls
has_many :contact_letters
has_many :contact_postalcards

# ContactEmail model
scope :from, lambda {|start| where("date_sent > ?", start)}
scope :to, lambda {|stop| where("date_sent < ?", stop)}

# ContactCall model
scope :from, lambda {|start| where("date_sent > ?", start)}
scope :to, lambda {|stop| where("date_sent < ?", stop)}
```

Then you can load what you want for each company like this:

```
emails_count = @company.contact_emails.from(some_date).to(some_date2).size
letters_count = @company.contact_letters.size
etc.
```

This solution will run many sql queries, but is good and clean for begining.

You can also write queries that load all emails within date range and count it with grouping by company. In this solution you would only have 5 queries (to load company and each "count").

EDIT:

I think that 50 to 100 queries is "not so bad" if it is not run too often. Always you can start with this and when your application is in production, then just look where are the slowest parts and then optimize them. However this query looks like it will probably cause some problems, so I suggest that you go in the way @Tim proposed. I just took a look on it and it seems that it is what you are looking for. But you should also have code that is in my answer, because you will probably need most of it in your application and you can use it to see if @Tim's approach is giving correct results.

According to you question, which companies you should show. So, you have some `@user` which is current user and in `User` model you have `has_many :companies`, so:

```
# in controller
# this should load all companies that belongs to @user and has at least one contact
@companies = @user.companies.joins(:contacts).where("contacts.id is not null")

# in view
<% @companies.each do |item| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to item.co_name, company_path(item.comp_id) %></td>
    <td><%= item.contact_emails.from(some_date).to(some_date2).size %> </td>
    <td><%= item.contact_postalcards.size %></td>
    <td><%= item.contact_calls.from(some_date).to(some_date2).size %></td>
 </tr>
<% end %>
```

If one company doesn't have any calls, but has emails contacts, it will just display 0 in calls column and some number in emails column.

Comment: aha -- I should perhaps use the through which I don't....that would probably simplify things.  I would then need to loop through multiple companies and do 5 queries per company, right?  I'd have a report with say 10-20 companies, is that a light load?

Comment: I think I want to go with a more readable approach for now -- but I don't know how to gauge if I am running "too many queries" --- thoughts?  10-20 companies for a single user

Comment: The challenge I have is that I have emails, calls, postalcards, and letters -- and some comapnies have only a subset of any one of these....so I don't think I can load all in an email date range because I still need to output it as a matrix...

Comment: How do I find which companies to display -- I only display companies that have at least one activity...but I don't want to show duplicates...I guess it would be doable?

Comment: thanks -- let me run with it --- it sounds like the choice is yours for redability and @Tim's for single sql?

Comment: I wasn't clear on part of your answer -- did you say the SQL was right in yours and it gives the same as @Tim's?

Comment: Hi, if there were no emails (or calls or whatever) sent, it looks like it will still display the company name?

Comment: @Angela: if you do it like in my answer, it should give the same result as Tim's answer, but by result I didn't mean "the same query". And this line in my code which load `@companies` will load only those companies which have at least one associated contact (even if this contact has no emial, nor phone call etc.).

Comment: ahhh...okay, I'm trying to only show those companies that has an associate email or phone call.....how could I do that?

Comment: Hi, just wanted to know what you meant by this:  However this query looks like it will probably cause some problems, so I suggest that you go in the way @Tim proposed

Comment: I think I am having a hard time understanding @tim's solution and for now would like yours to get working -- I need to get only those companies where there's been activity in the dates

Comment: @Angela: By "problems" I meant that it can be slow and @Tim's answer is better in that.